# Using Loop and Cursor in same mysql procedure showing error

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code is working properly. But when i am enabling the commented area (cursor), then the code showing error. Please help to fix the issue.

*Scenario: The code allow some parameter. It will prepare the data in a table and then the cursor will take data from that table and output that data.*

***Same Parameter: call prGetInsuranceData_Multiple(2, 'Saroar,Ahmed', '20,30')***

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `surokkha_db`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `prGetInsuranceData_Multiple`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `prGetInsuranceData_Multiple`
(
    PeopleToBeCovered INT,
    IN NAME VARCHAR(4000),
    IN AGE VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    -- declare loop variables
    DECLARE V_Name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE V_AGE INT;
    DECLARE X INT DEFAULT 0;
    
    -- declare cursor variables
    DECLARE Cur_Finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Cur_Name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE Cur_Age INT;
    
    -- create a table with comma separated values (Name with age in table format)
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer
    (
        NAME VARCHAR(255),
        AGE INT
    );
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer1
    (
        NAME VARCHAR(255),
        AGE INT
    );
    
    SET X = 1;
    BEGIN 
    WHILE X <= PeopleToBeCovered DO
        SET V_Name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,',',X),',',-1);
        SET V_Age = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(AGE,',',X),',',-1);
        SET X = X + 1;
        INSERT INTO TempCustomer VALUES(V_Name, V_Age);
    END WHILE;
    END;
    
    /*
    -- declare cursor
    DECLARE cur_NameWithAge 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT NAME, AGE FROM TempCustomer;
    
    
    -- declare NOT FOUND handler
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
    
    OPEN cur_NameWithAge;
    GetNameWithAge: LOOP
        FETCH cur_NameWithAge INTO Cur_Name, Cur_Age;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE GetNameWithAge;
        END IF;
        
        -- get data and insert into table
        INSERT INTO TempCustomer1 VALUES(Cur_Name, Cur_Age);
    END LOOP GetNameWithAge;
    CLOSE cur_NameWithAge;
    */
        
    SELECT * FROM TempCustomer;
    
    -- as after setting cursor the data is not needed, thats why drop the tables
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer1;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please update your question with the error you are getting

Comment: @NickW the erro is  that you can't DECLARE variables at that point, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to pout the loop and its declarations in a BEGIn ENd

Still i needed to reprogram the hole thing, because your code threw error, that i couldn't find

> ```
> create procedure prGetInsuranceData_Multiple(
>     IN PeopleToBeCovered INT,
>     IN _NAME VARCHAR(4000),
>     IN _AGE VARCHAR(200))
> begin
>     DECLARE V_Name VARCHAR(255);
>     DECLARE V_AGE INT;
>     DECLARE X INT DEFAULT 0;
>   drop temporary table if exists TempCustomer;
>   drop temporary table if exists TempCustomer1;
>   create temporary table TempCustomer( NAME VARCHAR(255),AGE int );
>   create temporary table TempCustomer1(NAME VARCHAR(255),AGE int);
>
>     SET X = 1;
>     BEGIN
>     WHILE X <= PeopleToBeCovered DO
>         SET V_Name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_NAME,',',X),',',-1);
>         SET V_Age = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_AGE,',',X),',',-1);
>         SET X = X + 1;
>         
>         INSERT INTO TempCustomer VALUES(V_Name,V_Age);
>     END WHILE;
>     END;
>
>   BEGIN
>       DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>       DECLARE v_id int ;
>       DECLARE v_name varchar(255);
>
>       declare cur_NameWithAge cursor for select NAME,AGE from TempCustomer;
>               DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>                   FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;  
>       open cur_NameWithAge;
>       GetNameWithAge: LOOP 
>           fetch cur_NameWithAge into v_name,v_id;
>           IF finished = 1 THEN 
>               LEAVE GetNameWithAge;
>           END IF;
>           INSERT INTO TempCustomer1 VALUES (v_name,v_id);
>       END LOOP GetNameWithAge;
>       CLOSE cur_NameWithAge;
>   END;
>   select * FROM TempCustomer;
>    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer1;
>    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE TempCustomer1;
> end
> ```

> ```
> call prGetInsuranceData_Multiple(2, 'Saroar,Ahmed', '20,30')
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME   | AGE
> :----- | --:
> Saroar |  20
> Ahmed  |  30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e2b9e9a67d0decf4b97b5d41f3b294a)*